# In-Cell Calls to Excel VBA Functions Not Updating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am having difficulty with a VBA function called from an Excel cell not automatically updating or updating manually with F9, Shift+F9, etc.

I'm Using "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20166) 32-bit" on Windows 10.

I have a table of various values used to prepare a budget. Each Column is a team member, and each row is a task. Each user is assigned hours for each task. Each task is assigned a multiplier by name.

For a simple example:

| Task [cellA1] | Person 1 | Person 2 | Multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First Task | 1.00 | 0.25 | Topic |
| Second Task | 0.05 | 0.15 | Participant |

As shown, Person 1 requires 1 hour per topic and 0.05 hours per Participant. Person 2 requires 0.25 hours per topic and 0.15 hours per Participant.

The number of Topics and Participants are contained in named ranges (i.e., "_topics", "_participants"). "Topic" and "Participant" are place holder names. What the are is unimportant (they could be "Dogs" or "Cats"). What is important is each has a single numeric value assiged to it. Tasks may share multipliers (i.e., more than one row may use "Topic").

The objective is to model the requirements of a complex budget (many members and many tasks), with very simple inputs (changing the number of topics, number of participants, etc.)

If this were a small table, I would use an in-cell formula like:

```
=sumif(D1:D2,"Topic",B1:B2) * _topic + sumif(D1:D2,"Participant",B1:B2) * _participants
```

If _topic = 5 and _participant = 10, the total for Person 1 would be 5.5 `(1 * 5 + 0.05 * 10)`.

In my case there are many rows and many multipliers, and there is also a second another column that assigns the task to a project phase, so I wrote a VBA function to keep the in-cell content legible and make it easier to add items in the future. Its not elegant, but it does what I need.

```
Function SUM_MEMBER_VALUES(phase As String, data_range As Range, phase_range As Range, mult_range As Range)

p = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Project")
mc = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Market_collections") * _
    Range("_markets_collections").Value
mr = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Market_calls") * _
    Range("_markets_calls").Value
c = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Caller") * _
    Range("_callers").Value
b = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand") * _
    Range("_brands").Value
bmc = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Market_collections") * _
    Range("_brand_markets_collections").Value
bmr = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Market_calls") * _
    Range("_brand_markets_calls").Value
bmpc = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Market-Product_collections") * _
    Range("_brand_market_products_collections").Value
bmpr = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Market-Product_calls") * _
    Range("_brand_market_products_calls").Value
bp = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Product") * _
    Range("_brand_products").Value
uc = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Unsuccessful Calls") * _
    Range("_calls_unsuccessful").Value
br = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Brand-Responses") * _
    Range("_brand_responses").Value
pr = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data_range, phase_range, phase, mult_range, "Product-Responses") * _
    Range("_product_responses").Value

SUM_MEMBER_VALUES = p + mc + mr + c + b + bmc + bmr + bmpc + bmpr + bp + uc + br + pr

End Function
```

The function is called in-cell in a table like:

| Phase [cellA1] | Person 1 | Person 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kick Off | =SUM_MEMBER_VALUES($A2,[person1's range],[task phase range],[task multiplier range]) | =SUM_MEMBER_VALUES($A2,[person2's range],[task phase range],[task multiplier range]) | =SUM(B2:B3) |

This function works. The problem I have is that it does not update automatically when I change the values for the named variables. So when _topic changes from 5 to 10, the results of `SUM_MEMBER_VALUES` do not change.

**Calculation options are set to automatic
F9, SHIFT+F9, and ribbon buttons to recalculate do not trigger the update
The file is macro enabled, and I have tried closing/reopening the file and rebooting the computer.**

The only way I have been able to update the reslts is to manually enter and hit return for each cell that calls `SUM_MEMBER_VALUES`. Ignoring that is is cumbersome, its also dangerous as its easy to miss updating a cell (especially if someone other than me uses the model which is the intent).

All I can think of is that it may not be recognizing that the values changed because of how the values are being passed to or referenced by the function (i.e., I passed a value as a Range, and the Range did not change, even if the contents in the Range did). I can't think of a workaround though.

*QUESTION:* Is there a way to ensure that as input vlues change, the VBA function updates automatically?

**UPDATE**
`SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+F9` Rebuilds the dependency tree and does a full recalculation. Also, adding `Application.Volatile` to the top of the function should force a recalculation everytime a change is made to the worksheet; however some contributors have warned against this as it forces the update even if an update isn't needed. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/refresh-excel-vba-function-results)

This solves my immediate needs, but I am curious if anyone has asolution between the to solutions (not needing a manual recalc and not recalculating everytime a font changes).

Comment: Sounds like for automatic calculation of a UDF you'll need all items that the calculation is based upon as arguments for your funcion. Instead of redoing your whole function wrapping it with an onchange event may work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible compromise would be to add static variables to the function that contain the "old" values in the table and skip the remainder of code if there is no change... clear as mud?

Let's say the ListObject name is Tbl1, and the ListColumn names are your column header names (Task, Person 1, Person 2, Multiplier).

```
Static sTaskOld$, sP1Old$, sP2Old$, sMultOld$
Dim sTask$, sP1$, sP2$, sMult$

Application.Volatile
sTask = Join(Application.Transpose([Tbl1[Task]]),"")
sP1 = Join(Application.Transpose([Tbl1[Person 1]]),"")
sP2 = Join(Application.Transpose([Tbl1[Person 2]]),"")
sMult = Join(Application.Transpose([Tbl1[Multiplier]]),"")

'first recalc, static variables will be null
if sTask<>sTaskOld or sP1<>sP1Old or sP2<>sP2Old or sMult<>sMultOld then
...
end if

'save existing values to static variables
sTaskOld = sTask
sP1Old = sP1
sP2Old = sP2
sMultOld = sMult
```

Of course, you could use an array instead of individual variables, but this example is conceptual.

The function would still fire, but at least you wouldn't be spending much processing time comparing the old vs. current values.